# how does Google append search parameters to url without reloading page?

Tags: php, javascript, css

How does Google append search parameters to url without reloading page?

Does anyone know how they do it? I know about the HASH trick and the webkit pushState function. I don't think they are using either.

Their solution is cross browser compatible, do they use a combination of different methods for each browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google uses the hash-trick. Notice that all the parameters are after

```
http://www.google.com/#
```

**Edit:** If you entered the page with other parameters, the `#` may be further out in the link.

Comment: We must be using a different search engine... I don't see any # in my searches =0

Comment: On instant search you will find it does.

Comment: Google instant on Chrome, Firefox and Safari all use the # here. What search engine are you using? :-)

Comment: Gotcha, the instant search does use it! I was expecting the # to be after the google.com/# but it's further down the parameter list only when the instant search is used. Thanks

Comment: That explains the confusion. Added it to my answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can add parameters after the hash sign (`#`) without reloading the page using the `window.location.hash` property.